# updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind in github. How can i avoid this kind of problem

Tags: html, github

I am new to Github. I have four folders on my computer which contains multiple HTML/CSS files. I want to push those four folders to a GitHub repository call CSS. But whenever I write push command in git bash I am seeing this error:[image]

Please, someone, help me to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Please post text instead of pictures of text

Comment: @possum extremely sorry. I thought the picture would be a great way to understand the error.

Answer (score 0):

The git repo has changes pushed to it, by someone else possibly. You need to run `git pull` to merge the changes in locally, solve any conflicts if they exist and then you'll be able to push.

Comment: Elliot thanks a lot. Solved it.